# ILookup<TKey, TVal> vs. IGrouping<TKey, TVal>

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, igrouping, ilookup

I've been having trouble articulating the differences between [`ILookup<TKey, TVal>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291.aspx) and [`IGrouping<TKey, TVal>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx), and am curious if I understand it correctly now.  LINQ compounded the issue by producing sequences of `IGrouping` items while also giving me a `ToLookup` extension method. So it felt like they were the same until I looked more closely.

```
var q1 = 
    from n in N
    group n by n.MyKey into g
    select g;
// q1 is IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TVal>>
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
var q2 = N.GroupBy(n => n.MyKey, n => n);
// q2 is IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TVal>>
```

Which looks a lot like:

```
var q3 = N.ToLookup(n => n.MyKey, n => n);
// q3 is ILookup<TKey, TVal>
```

Am I correct in the following analogies?

1. An `IGrouping<TKey, TVal>` is a single group (i.e. a keyed sequence), analogous to `KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal>` where the value is actually a sequence of elements (rather than a single element)
2. An `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TVal>>` is a sequence of those (similar to what you get when iterating over an `IDictionary<TKey, TVal>`
3. An `ILookup<TKey, TVal>` is more like a `IDictionary<TKey, TVal>` where the value is actually a sequence of elements

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Yes, all of those are correct.

And `ILookup<TKey, TValue>` also extends `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>>` so you can iterate over all the key/collection pairs as well as (or instead of) just looking up particular keys.

I basically think of `ILookup<TKey,TValue>` as being like `IDictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>>`.

Bear in mind that `ToLookup` is a "do it now" operation (immediate execution)  whereas a `GroupBy` is deferred. As it happens, with the way that "pull LINQ" works, when you start pulling `IGrouping`s from the result of a `GroupBy`, it has to read all the data anyway (because you can't switch group midway through) whereas in other implementations it may be able to produce a streaming result. (It does in Push LINQ; I would expect LINQ to Events to be the same.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't come across thinking of Linq in terms of push/pull before. When I went to Google it I came across one of your blogs so I'll check that out. Sounds like an interesting way to think about it.

Comment: I still think that these differences don't justify 2 different interfaces. I think that the Library designer should have decided for just one interface. Maybe just a personal taste that here is something not explicit enough.

Comment: Is it me or is there some confusion with GroupBy vs GroupJoin? Those are only _conceptually_ related. Perhaps it is just a typo in the answer though.

Comment: @rudimeter, ILookup also adds a indexer and a Contains method. I think the reason for the two interfaces is each interface expresses a different intention.  IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>> is useful if you are planning to loop through the entire collection. But if you are looking for only a subset of groups, then ILookup is a better choice using the indexer.

Comment: For example, looping through a vehicleModelGroups and using if/else to select a group of model cars for particular mfg is not as concise nor expresses the intention as clearly as var hondaModels = vehicleModelLookup("Honda")

Answer (score 13):

`GroupBy` and `ToLookUp` has almost same functionality **EXCEPT** this: [Reference](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-grouping-operator-groupby-tolookup)

> GroupBy: The GroupBy operator returns groups of elements based on some
>   key value. Each group is represented by IGrouping
>   object.
>
> ToLookup: ToLookup is the same as GroupBy; the only difference
>   is the execution of GroupBy is deferred whereas ToLookup execution is
>   immediate.

Lets clear the difference using sample code. suppose that we have a class representing `Person` model:

```
class Personnel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

after that we define a list of `personnels` as below:

```
 var personnels = new List<Personnel>
    {
        new Personnel { Id = 1, FullName = "P1", Level = 1 },
        new Personnel { Id = 2, FullName = "P2", Level = 2 },
        new Personnel { Id = 3, FullName = "P3", Level = 1 },
        new Personnel { Id = 4, FullName = "P4", Level = 1 },
        new Personnel { Id = 5, FullName = "P5", Level =2 },
        new Personnel { Id = 6, FullName = "P6", Level = 2 },
        new Personnel { Id = 7, FullName = "P7", Level = 2 }
    };
```

Now I need to get the `personnels` grouped by their level. I have two approach here. using `GroupBy` or `ToLookUp`. If I use `GroupBy`, as stated before, it will use deferred execution, this means, that when you iterate through the collection the next item may or may not be computed until it is called for.

```
 var groups = personnels.GroupBy(p => p.Level);
    personnels.RemoveAll(p => p.Level == 1);
    foreach (var product in groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(product.Key);
        foreach (var item in product)
            Console.WriteLine(item.Id + " >>> " + item.FullName + " >>> " + item.Level);
    }
```

In the above code, I firstly grouped the `personnels`, but before iterating it, I removed some `personnels`. As `GroupBy` uses deferred execution, so the final result will not include the removed items, because grouping will be computing in the `foreach` point here.

Output:

```
2
2 >>> P2 >>> 2
5 >>> P5 >>> 2
6 >>> P6 >>> 2
7 >>> P7 >>> 2
```

But if I rewrite the above code as below:(note that code is same as the previous code except `GroupBy` is replaced by `ToLookUp`)

```
 var groups = personnels.ToLookup(p => p.Level);
    personnels.RemoveAll(p => p.Level == 1);
    foreach (var product in groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(product.Key);
        foreach (var item in product)
            Console.WriteLine(item.Id + " >>> " + item.FullName + " >>> " + item.Level);
    }
```

As `ToLookUp` uses immediate execution, it means that when I call the `ToLookUp` method, result is generated and group is applied, so if I remove any item from `personnels` prior to iteration, that wont effect the final result.

Output:

```
1
1 >>> P1 >>> 1
3 >>> P3 >>> 1
4 >>> P4 >>> 1
2
2 >>> P2 >>> 2
5 >>> P5 >>> 2
6 >>> P6 >>> 2
7 >>> P7 >>> 2
```

Note: `GroupBy` and `ToLookUp` both return different types too.

You might use ToDictionary instead of ToLookUp, but you need to pay attention to this:([reference](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/03/24/c.net-little-wonders-the-tolookup-linq-extension-method.aspx))

> The usage of ToLookup() is very similar to that of ToDictionary(),
>   both allow you to specify key selectors, value selectors, and
>   comparers.  The main difference is that ToLookup() allows (and
>   expects) the duplicate keys whereas ToDictionary() does not

Comment: Thank you for your explicit explanation of this important difference between those two!

Answer (score 9):

There is another important difference between ILookup and IDictionary: the former enforces immutability in the sense that here are no methods for changing the data (except when the consumer performs an explicit cast). By contrast, IDictionary has methods like "Add" which allow changing the data. So, from the perspective of functional-programming and/or parallel programming, ILookup is nicer.

(Btw., it seems worth pointing out that the relationship between IEnumerable and IList is somewhat similar to the one between ILookup and IDictionary - the former is immutable, the latter is not.)

Comment: Why would you want an `ILookup` that has only a single-item value rather than a group? That's what a `Dictionary` is--or a `ReadOnlyDictionary` or `IReadOnlyDictionary` if you want it to be immutable.

Comment: @ErikE: I spotted your comment years after you wrote it and removed the obsolete sentence from the answer.

Comment: Okay, sounds good!