# Create List by Unique Key with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class of type Dependency:

```
class Dependency
{
    public int Source;
    public int Target:
}
```

Given a list of `List<Dependency>` I would have the following list (each line is a Source/Target pair):

```
1, 2
1, 5
2, 1
3, 4
3, 6
```

Is it possible to merge them with Linq so that the following is produced `List<Tuple<int,List<int>>`:

```
1, [2,5]
2, [1]
3, [4,6]
```

Given a larger list of a couple of thousand items, would using Linq be the fastest way to perform the above merge?

Comment: So are `Source` and `Target` separate lists, or is it a class with properties `Source` and `Target`?

Comment: Revised question to include the class type

Comment: Group by `Source` and the rest should be easy. Can't speak about speed, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ group by operator like this:

```
var items = new List<Dependency>();
// add your items to list

var result = (from i in items
             group i by i.Source
             into gr
             select new Tuple<int, List<int>>(gr.Key, gr.Select(a => a.Target).ToList())).ToList();
```

The above query should be quite fast, although it is hard to compare with other ways of achieving the same thing. I suggest testing that in practice - write alternative implementation and compare the performance.

Comment: If you would likr the methods equivalent: `items.GroupBy(x=>x.Source,(k,x)=>new Tuple<int,List<int>>(k,x.Select(g=>g.Target).ToList())).ToList();`

Answer (score 3):

> <sub>**Note:** [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26084081/240733) recommends C#'s `group into` syntax. My answer shows something similar, namely the `.ToLookup(…)` operator. If you're asking what the difference between these two is, see e.g. the following question: [ILookup<TKey, TVal> vs. IGrouping<TKey, TVal>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1337539/240733).</sub>

The following solution won't yield a `List<Tuple<int, List<int>>>`, and I cannot say whether it is the fastest solution, but it's quite probably the most succinct:

```
ILookup<int,int> multiMap = dependencies.ToLookup(d => d.Source, d => d.Target);
```

The [`.ToLookup(…)` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) groups your `dependencies` by their `Source` property (as specified by the first lambda), and instead of putting complete `Dependency` objects into the output, it only selects their `Target` values (as specified by the second, optional lambda).

What you get is an [`ILookup<TKey,TElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534291.aspx), which is essentially like a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, except that there can be several elements (values) per key.

Here's an example how you can iterate over all the values in such a data structure (a so-called [multimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap)):

```
foreach (IGrouping<int,int> grouping in multiMap)  // enumerate over all groups
foreach (int target in grouping)  // enumerate over all values in one specific group
{
    int source = grouping.Key;  // get the key value of the group
    …
}
```