# How can interface IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement> yield multiple values?

Tags: c#, linq, interface, igrouping, ilookup

I wonder what point I overlook. [`IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2?view=netframework-4.8) is used by LINQ `GroupBy`. Further, the same logic is applied to `ILookup`, IIRC. Accordingly, they can return multiple values subject to the key specified. However, instead, I would expect the following signature to be done so.

```
interface IGrouping<out TKey, out IEnumerable<TElement>>
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Originally, it implements `IEnumerable<TElement>` and `IEnumerable` for backward compatibility. Does this accomplish the same task? If yes, how? I don't understand.

```
public interface ILookup<TKey,TElement> : IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TElement>>
```

Does the followed mean `ILookup` used by `Join/GroupJoin` has multiple keys with the association of multiple values? Could you exemplify? I've looked [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337539/ilookuptkey-tval-vs-igroupingtkey-tval), but don't understand the difference, except that their lazy evaluation vs immediate evaluation semantics.

---

**Not to do complicate matter further**, but the output may help for everyone.

[image]

Comment: It is the interfaces that are implemented that satisfy the foreach/LINQ statements, the second type parameter is the type of elements that are served, the collection-behavior comes from implementing the IEnumerable interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the declaration of [`IGrouping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2?view=netframework-4.8),

```
public interface IGrouping<out TKey,out TElement> : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<out TElement>
```

You can see that it says "`IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` is a kind of `IEnumerable<TElement>`".

It's a special kind of `IEnumerable<TElement>`. Special in what way? It has a `Key` associated.

---

And no, this is not valid C# syntax:

```
interface IGrouping<out TKey, out IEnumerable<TElement>>
```

Remember that this is an interface *declaration*, and in the `<>`, it is declaring the type parameters, which are identifiers, for the interface. `IEnumerable<TElement>` is not a valid identifier. You also seem to want to refer to the existing interface `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`, but it makes no sense to put it in this place in the declaration, the same way that it wouldn't make sense to write `interface Foo<List<T>>` as an interface declaration in Java.

If you mean:

```
interface IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement> where TElement : IEnumerable
```

that *could* work, and there are many ways in which you can design this `IGrouping` interface. The following way probably makes sense to you the most?

```
interface IMyGrouping<TKey, TElement> {
    TKey Key { get; }
    IEnumerable<TElement> Elements { get; }
}
```

But what's really great about .NET framework's design is that it *implements an existing interface*, and that allows it to be used as an `IEnumerable<TElement>` directly, which is a very powerful thing. If your class have the ability that the interface promises, implement that interface. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848442/what-exactly-is-interface-based-programming).

> Does the followed mean ILookup used by GroupBy has multiple keys with the association of multiple values?

Yes. Since `ILookup` implements `IEnumerable<IGrouping>`, and `IGrouping` implements `IEnumerable`, `ILookup` is *kind of* like a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable>` (forgive me using the generics notation very loosely here). So an `ILookup` an enumerable of enumerables, i.e. like a 2D array. **The difference is,** that each inner "array" has a `Key`, since the inner "arrays" are actually `IGrouping`s.

Comment: I beg your pardon, my questions are generally verbose, maybe meaningless too. However, _**logically**_ is there any wrong with my syntax? And do you have any idea why the syntax is wrong?

Comment: _It's a special kind of IEnumerable<TElement>. Special in what way? It has a Key associated._ +1, by the way.

Comment: @snr Not logically wrong, this is why I provided a "if you mean..." part to try to guess at what you mean by that. You are supposed to declare type parameters in those `<>`, you are not supposed to put an existing type, `IEnumerable<TElement>` there. Type parameters can't be parameterised.

Comment: @snr See the edit. I've tried to explain/guess why .NET framework chose to design `IGrouping` this way, as opposed to some other way.

Comment: The difference is, that each inner "array" has a Key, since the inner "arrays" are actually IGroupings. --> is it like as exactly seen the output of the picture added? ((:

Comment: @snr Yes. I would think that If you have seen that picture, you should have understood what an `ILookup` is. What's your misunderstanding exactly?

Comment: thanks a lot sir. I'm not as much as a genius like you (: A bit hard to grasp semantics.